# The innerHTML loop is not working

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<!-- Style Sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!-- Style Sheet -->



<script>

window.onload = function(){
 createimages();
 }

function createimages(){
 var n = createScrambledArray(16);
 var img = ["chicken-icon","crab-icon","dolphin-icon","gold-fish-icon","horse-icon","octopus-icon","rabbit-icon","turtle-icon"];
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
 for(var i = 0; i<n.length; i++){
  element.innerHTML = "<p>Test</p>";
 }
}

function createScrambledArray(n) {
    var num = [n];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        while (num.indexOf(temp) >= 0) {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        }
        nums.push(temp);
    }
    return nums;
}

function clickhandler(x){
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
 var getelement = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
 
}

</script>

<body>

<h1>MATCHING GAME </h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(0)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(1)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(2)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(3)"></div>
    
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(4)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(5)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(6)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(7)"></div>
    
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(8)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(9)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(10)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(11)"></div>

    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(12)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(13)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(14)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(15)"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Quite simple and silly mistake question.

Apparently I have been getting an issue of not being able to put new elements on my following divs inside the container (box) so I am not sure if that's the naming issue or all.

line for `element.innerHTML = "<p>Test</p>";` refuses to work

Comment: *Uncaught ReferenceError: nums is not defined*

Comment: I suggest you study how to format SO posts (you can use back-ticks to format code inside sentences, and "protect" HTML tags), and also proof-read your posts. Also, I suggest you learn how to debug your programs, at a minimum learning how to view the console for errors. Finally, there is no need to include the `<DOCTYPE>` and other boilerplate, since it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes: `nums` is not an array you have defined. It should be `num`.

Also, your loop should be like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<n.length; i++){
        element[i].innerHTML = "<p>Test</p>";  //Since element is a collection
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<!-- Style Sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!-- Style Sheet -->



<script>

window.onload = function(){
 createimages();
 }

function createimages(){
 var n = createScrambledArray(16);
 var img = ["chicken-icon","crab-icon","dolphin-icon","gold-fish-icon","horse-icon","octopus-icon","rabbit-icon","turtle-icon"];
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
 for(var i = 0; i<n.length; i++){
  element[i].innerHTML = "<p>Test</p>";
 }
}

function createScrambledArray(n) {
    var num = [n];

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        while (num.indexOf(temp) >= 0) {
            temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        }
        num.push(temp);
    }
    console.log(num);
  return num;
}

function clickhandler(x){
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
 var getelement = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
 
}

</script>

<body>

<h1>MATCHING GAME </h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(0)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(1)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(2)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(3)"></div>
    
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(4)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(5)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(6)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(7)"></div>
    
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(8)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(9)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(10)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(11)"></div>

    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(12)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(13)"></div>
    <div class="box spacing" onclick="clickhandler(14)"></div>
    <div class="box" onclick="clickhandler(15)"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the answer!!

Comment: Thanks!. You may accept the answer so that this question does not remain open

Comment: The question remains open even after an answer is accepted.